# Why does ElasticSearch give a lower score to a term when it's with more terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index (on a local, testing, cluster), with some fields using the simple analizer.

When I search for a term, the results where the term is in a field with more terms, get a lower score - why is that? I couldn't find any reference.

For example, 'koala' in a boolean search returns:

- (title 'a koala'): score 0.04500804
- (title 'how the Koala 1234'): score 0.02250402

In the query explanation, the fieldNorm is 1.0 in the first case, and 0.5 in the second.

Is it possible to return a score indipendent from the number of terms in the field?

Comment: "a koala" is closer to "koala" than "how the Koala 1234". Are you looking to return a term query without scoring? Or do you want to have all the documents with "koala" to be scored equally without "how the 1234" being considered in the score?

Comment: The second! I would expect them to have the same score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a bool must term query of koala with all documents scoring equal on "koala". You could use the constant score query to basically remove the score from your query.

Here is a runnable example
http://sense.qbox.io/gist/21ae7b7e743dc30d66309f2a6b93043ded4ee401

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html